# How to retrieve the value of ngClass in angular test?

Tags: angular, jasmine

This is my component.html file which contains the ngClass attribute in the second span element:

```
<span class="container">
  <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="disabled" (click)="onButtonClicked()">
    <mat-icon>{{icon}}</mat-icon>
    <span class="badge" [ngClass]="((themes$ | async)[(activeTheme$ | async)].accent)" color="accent" *ngIf="badgeCount > 0">{{parseBadgeCount()}}</span>
  </button>
</span>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a reason a simple check to see if that span has the expected class will not work?

Comment: I am new to front-end dev.. let's say I use local referencing on that span element (#activeTheme), and in my component.ts: @ViewChild('activeTheme') activeTheme: ElementRef; .. then I can get the value like this: this.activeTheme.nativeElement.value .. though I need to get the value of the ngClass attribute. I actually don't know how to get individual attribute values from nested elements..

Comment: Are you using Jasmine for your testing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are writing tests in Jasmine, you can verify things multiple ways. Here are a few examples. The last two are specifically looking at the value of the [ngClass] attribute, whereas the first two are just checking to see if a certain class was applied.

```js
it('should have the "correct-class" CSS class applied', () => {
    // Do whatever you need for your arrange/act portions of your test
    ...

    // Assert
    const badge = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.badge'));
    expect(badge.classes['correct-class']).toBeTruthy();
});

it('should have the "correct-class" CSS class applied', () => {
    // Do whatever you need for your arrange/act portions of your test
    ...

    // Assert
    const badge: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.badge')).nativeElement;
    expect(badge.classList).toContain('correct-class');
});

it('should have [ngClass] resolve to "correct-class"', () => {
    // Do whatever you need for your arrange/act portions of your test
    ...

    // Assert
    const badge = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.badge'));
    expect(badge.attributes['ng-reflect-ng-class']).toBe('correct-class');
});

it('should have [ngClass] resolve to "correct-class"', () => {
    // Do whatever you need for your arrange/act portions of your test
    ...

    // Assert
    const badge: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.badge')).nativeElement;
    expect(badge.attributes['ng-reflect-ng-class'].value).toBe('correct-class');
});
```

Comment: when the class is an object with several classes, none of these work, because value is a string with value "[object Object]".

Comment: @JuanguiJordán in this case we can assert expect(badge.classes['correct-class']).toBeTruthy();

Comment: I am using a property on a component to set the `ngClass` and for some reasons nothing works for me. I.e. I am using the `[ngClass]="nameOfTheComponentProp"`. The `.classes[]` approach returns `undefined` for my class.

Comment: I just forgot to pass the value to the property. I.e. I used in parent html not a variable, but a string. I.e. `<child prop="foo" [prop2]="bar"></child>`. While the `prop2` worked, the `prop` did not. I changed to `<child [prop]="foo" [prop2]="bar"></child>` to fix the issue.